# How do I declare a parameter type as a .NET framework type that must be explicitly loaded?

Tags: powershell, parameters, .net-assembly

I want to be able to pass a `Color` type from `System.Drawing` into my PowerShell script. However, unless I explicitly load the `System.Drawing.dll` prior to running my script and I don't want to have people do that.

I get this error unless I load the dll outside of the script:

> Unable to find type [System.Drawing.Color]

My PowerShell `Param` declaration looks like this:

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $TargetFile,
    [Parameter()][int] $Thickness = 1,
    [Parameter()][Switch] $UseTopLeftColor = $false,
    [Parameter()][System.Drawing.Color] $BorderColor = [System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(195,195,195)
)
```

The code to load the DLL reference is this:

```
[Void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile("C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Drawing.dll")
```

How can I define a dependency on the DLL for the script and have it automatically reference the DLL?

Comment: By using exactly that line and loading the assembly.

Comment: Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms

Comment: Yeah but I thought you couldn't have any lines above the Param? Per my question, I don't want people who are using this script at work to have to run a command first. Or is that why Add-Type can do? But can you run that before Param is evaluated?

Comment: @Thraka No, you can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add-Type` is just a more convenient way of writing `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile()`. Neither can be used before `Param()` in a script.

If you want to be able to run the PowerShell script from anywhere, I'd suggest specifying one parameter per basic color, and then calculating the color in the script. That way you can also validate each value:

```
Param(
  [Parameter(Position=0)]
  [ValidateRange(0,255)]
  [int]$BorderRed = 195,
  [Parameter(Position=1)]
  [ValidateRange(0,255)]
  [int]$BorderGreen = 195,
  [Parameter(Position=2)]
  [ValidateRange(0,255)]
  [int]$BorderBlue = 195
)

Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Drawing'

[Drawing.Color]::FromArgb($BorderRed, $BorderGreen, $BorderBlue)
```

Trying to specify the color as a list of 3 values to a single parameter would be difficult to implement. From outside PowerShell you can't really pass an array to a parameter, so you'd have to specify something like a comma-separated string and parse that into 3 integer values.

Passing color names as a single parameter would work, though:

```
Param(
  [Parameter()]
  [string]$BorderColor = 'Blue'
)

Add-Type -Assembly 'System.Drawing'

[Drawing.Color]::$BorderColor
```